# GPS Data Service

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity, gps

I am trying to program a service that sends GPS location data to a server at settable time intervals. Being fairly new to android, this is not turning out as easy as I was hoping and the internet doesn't really seem to be helping me either. The service should...

- Start at boot
- be able to read settings, that are anytime changeable from an activity/app and also apply these settings in real time without having to reboot the phone
- be able to upload the data to the internet (httpRequest)
- Not cause my phone to crash (previous attempts caused my phone to crash)

What is the best solution? What direction should I be heading in?

In terms of the LocationListener itself, what is here the best solution?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "the internet doesn't really seem to be helping me either": Really? Have you tried the search feature on this site?

Comment: Yeah, there are a LOT of articles reagarding each and every part of your requirements.

Comment: I guess you're not looking for the right thing. In Android, "Service"s are not quite the same as in Windows.

Comment: I tried using a broadcastreceiver (which didn't actually work), and I have to correct myself as I have found several articles, but implementing the ideas mentioned has been a little tricky. I'm just not sure how to gather the GPS data- whether to do it in a thread of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 7 minutes of search, here are a few articles to help you out:

> Start at boot

This is done using a BroadcastReceiver. Check out this answer for the **exact** way to implement it: [Android -Starting Service at Boot Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562734/android-starting-service-at-boot-time)

> be able to read settings, that are anytime changeable from an
>   activity/app and also apply these settings in real time without having
>   to reboot the phone

**EDIT** As per the OP's comment, one can use [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) to create a Settings page for an app. [This article](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-preferences-activity-example/) shows basic implementation of a PreferenceActivity, while this [excellent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614719/how-do-i-get-the-sharedpreferences-from-a-preferenceactivity-in-android) shows how to read these preferences from the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). And, yes SharedPreferencs will persist after a reboot (they don't persist after an app uninstall though).

> be able to upload the data to the internet (httpRequest)

On how to make HTTPRequests in android: [Make an HTTP request with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android)

> Not cause my phone to crash (previous attempts caused my phone to
>   crash)

This one really depends on you. But, hey, you can always search this site for all and every possible error you get.

> In terms of the LocationListener itself, what is here the best
>   solution?

Try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709030/get-gps-location-in-a-broadcast-receiver-or-service-to-broadcast-receiver-data-t/7709140#7709140) (which has complete code example), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218075/android-location-listener).

Comment: Under settings I meant things like the time interval between sending of the data, actually enabling/disabling the service and the ID required to register the data when connecting to the server.

Comment: @user2505059 you mean a [Preference Activity](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-preferences-activity-example/)?

Comment: For example, but are the preferences kept after rebooting?

Comment: Thanks the problem is nearly solved! The remaining problem is when changing the preferences- how do I get the changed preferences to be applied immediately?

Comment: @user2505059 You would need to implement a [OnPreferencesChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html). Your listener gets a reference to the sharedPrefs that were changed, and a key to access the new value. Beware of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542938/sharedpreferences-onsharedpreferencechangelistener-not-being-called-consistently) problem though. If you want me to provide you with more details, please amend your question first.